# How/why does x.append(x.pop(0)) work in Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and one of the exercises is to reorder the values in the array from

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

to

```
x = ['c', 'a', 'b']
```

The solution is

```
x.append(x.pop(0))
```

My question is, Since `x.pop(0)` is inside the parentheses for `x.append()`, how does `append()` know what the value is of `x[0]` since the `pop()` method removed it because expressions inside parentheses are evaluated first? My gut tells me it shouldn't work since there'd be no value to append, yet it does work. I'd like to understand why.

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: The solution should have been `x.insert(0, x.pop())` if the expected result was `['c', 'a', 'b']`. Is this a copy & paste error?

Comment: The fact that "expressions inside the parentheses are evaluated first" is the key.  The `x.pop(0)` will run and return a value before `append` ever gets called.

Comment: You could also do `x[0], x[-1] = x[-1], x[0]` or `x.insert(0, x.pop())`. The last one seems marginally faster, but I think the first one more clearly communicates the intent to swap the two values.

Comment: `x.reverse()` does the same thing and is much faster.  Not a very efficient tutorial :^)

Answer (score 2):

The `pop` method returns the element it removes, so `x.append(x.pop(0))` is equivalent to:

```python
removed_element = x.pop(0)
x.append(removed_element)
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that I understand that pop() not only removes a value, but also returns that value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`x.pop(0)` returns the value being popped from the list. It's basically the same as the following:

```py
removed_value = x.pop(0)
x.append(removed_value)
```

Since the popped value is returned by the `.pop()` function, it can be easily used as input for the `.append()` function.